# Flutter TextField blocks horizontal scrolling on Table

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, singlechildscrollview

I have a table that need to scroll vertically and horizontally. I managed to do this by wrapping the table in 2 scrollviews. My issue is that if the user tries to scroll horizontally by swiping on the textfield, the horizontal scrolling isn't working.

I can however scroll horizontally when swiping on the headings, or outside the textfields.

Is there a way to disable the gestures on a textview. I tried setting scrollPhysics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() on the textfield to no avail.

Vertical scrolling works fine when swiping on the textfield.

```dart
class TableExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Table Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Card(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              child: Table(
                defaultColumnWidth: const FixedColumnWidth(75),
                border: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.grey),
                children: <TableRow>[
                  TableRow(children: [
                    Text('1'),
                    Text('2'),
                    Text('3'),
                    Text('4'),
                    Text('5'),
                    Text('6'),
                    Text('7'),
                    Text('8'),
                    Text('9'),
                    Text('10'),
                  ]),
                  TableRow(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextField(
                        scrollPhysics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      ),
                      TextField(),
                      TextField(),
                      TextField(),
                      TextField(),
                      TextField(),
                      TextField(),
                      TextField(),
                      TextField(),
                      TextField(),
                    ],
                  ),
                  TableRow(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextField(),
                      TextField(),
                      TextField(),
                      TextField(),
                      TextField(),
                      TextField(),
                      TextField(),
                      TextField(),
                      TextField(),
                      TextField(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```